# Set cluster name when using Cassandra CQL/JDBC driver

Tags: cassandra, cql

I'm using the Cassandra CQL/JDBC driver I got from [google code](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-jdbc/) but it doesn't seem to let me provide a cluster name - is there a way?

I'm using cluster names to ensure I don't run commands against a live system, it has a different cluster name to my dev systems.

Edit: Just to clarify, I have two totally separate Cassandra clusters, one live and one for test. They have different cluster names to ensure that I don't accidentally run test code meant for the test cluster on the live cluster. Therefore any client I need to use must let me set a cluster name. Hector does this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no inbuilt protection for checking cluster names for Cassandra clients.  It is built to ensure nodes from different clusters don't try and join together but not to ensure clients connect to the right cluster.  It would be possible to add this checking to a client though (since the cluster name is exposed to the client) but I'm not aware of any clients doing this.

I'd strongly recommend firewalling off your different environments to avoid this kind of mistake.  If that isn't possible, you should choose different ports to avoid confusion.  Change this with the 'rpc_port' setting in cassandra.yaml.

Comment: The most common way to segregate Cassandra does seem to be with a firewall.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to mirror the data on two different clusters. You cant access the same cluster with different names.

To rename your cluster (from the default 'Test Cluster') you edit the cassandra configuration file found in `location/of/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml`. Its the top line, if you need more details look at the datastax [configuration documentation](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/configuration/node_configuration#cluster-name) and explanation.